# Dropdownlist Binding with the list of objects in dot net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to bind the DDL list in MVC, but I am not getting the correct value. Please see the below line of code.

```
UserViewModel userVM = new UserViewModel();
CustomLogger.Write("Service Call: Get UserEmployeeId " + ": Start");
HttpResponseMessage response = await ServiceGet(ClientConfig.ServiceLayerUrl + ClientConfig.GetAllUsersUrl);
CustomLogger.Write("Service Call: Get UserEmployeeId " + ": End");

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var res = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(res);


    //select only UserEmployeeId  

    var userList = (from item in list select item);

    userVM.AvailableUsers = userList;

    return View(userVM);
}
else
{
    CustomLogger.Write("Service Call: Get UserEmployeeId " + ": Issue" + response);
    return null;
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserEmployeeId, new SelectList(Model.AvailableUsers, "UserEmployeeId"), "SELECT", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Output :
In DDL list, I am getting like
TMS.Common.Entities.User

I am not able to bind the value of the list in DDL.

[image]

Comment: Just repeat the same property name for both text & value from `SelectList`: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserEmployeeId, new SelectList(Model.AvailableUsers, "UserEmployeeId", "UserEmployeeId"), "SELECT", new { @class = "form-control" })`. Also you may try to convert into `List<SelectListItem>` first: `(from item in list select new SelectListItem { Text = item.UserEmployeeId, Value = item.UserEmployeeId })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually by using `new SelectList(Model.AvailableUsers, "UserEmployeeId")` you're trying to create `SelectList` with just 2 overloads, which is incorrect:

```
public SelectList(IEnumerable items, object selectedValue)
```

What you need is using [3 overload containing text and value field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.):

```
public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField)
```

Hence, the correct usage of your `DropDownListFor` should be like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserEmployeeId, new SelectList(Model.AvailableUsers, "UserEmployeeId", "UserEmployeeId"), "SELECT", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The second mistake is you're assigning `IQueryable` from this query:

```
var userList = (from item in list select item);
```

where `SelectList` first parameter requires `IEnumerable`, therefore just use `ToList()`:

```
var userList = (from item in list select item).ToList();
```

The `TMS.Common.Entities.User` type name appears because it implicitly calls `ToString()` to `IQueryable` instance stored inside `userList`.

Comment: Works perfect :) Thanks